# Complex SSRS Report to calculate a field

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, bids

I am stuck with this report pattern can anyone help me out how to deal with this situation? Here is what want to accomplish on SSRS

I have table 
      Units  distribution
High   10     (10/30) -33%
low    20     (20/30) -66%
total  30

how can we use the total value of high, low rows to calculate distribution?

[Sample Pic with formulas table and Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOykK.jpg)

and here I want to achieve data table on right on the picture, so I want to implement the formulas table pattern on Data table using SSRS, I have already pulled the data.

Thank you

Comment: i suppose if you can explain better so we can understand

Comment: i want to use the total values of High and low to calculate their distribution

Comment: instead of having it as a formula why don't do the calculation in the dataset

Comment: yes, I agree completely, let's say Total values are in a row, so how can I access that row value to calculate the contribution of each?

Comment: i guess the question is,... is the table static or dynamic?

Comment: it's dynamic, the table has to calculate the fields dynamically

Comment: what i meant was, does the row of the table grows or shrinks or it is always to going to be that structure?

Comment: it does not grow, it's a constant structure

Comment: that's my point... create a dataset that will return those rows as columns.. then display the table vertically (columns to rows) since the structure is fixed.

Comment: Cool man, This idea will work for me thank you for your help, I'll do that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dataset that will return those rows as columns.. then display the table vertically (columns to rows) since the structure is fixed.